# How to obtain lower and upper bounds for Ramsey number $R_k (3,3,\dots,3)$

Tags: combinatorics

$R_k(3,3,\dots,3)$ is the smallest integer s.t. any k-edge-coloring of complete graph $K_n$ has a monochromatic triangle.
We have the bounds: $$2^k \le R_k (3,3,\dots,3) \le (k+1)!$$
I wanted to do this by induction but there seemed to be to much work.
Is there any simpler way to solve this?

Comment: You only need induction for the upper bound. For the lower bound, simply identify the vertex set with $\{0,1\}^k$ and let the color of the edge between vertices $x=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots y_k)$ be the least $i$ such that $x_i\ne y_i.$ Note that the inequality $2^k\lt R_k(3,3,\dots,3)$ is strict.

Comment: @bof I find this induction not very intuitive. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @bof Sorry for this ambiguity. I mean the induction on the upper bound.

Comment: $R_k(3,3,\dots,3)\le(k+1)!$ fails for $k=1.$ For $k\ge2$ it's true, and in fact $$R_k(3,3,\dots,3)\le\lceil k!e\rceil\le(k+1)!.$$

Comment: Let me write $a_k=R_k(3,3,\dots,3).$ To prove the upper bound by induction, use the inequality $$a_{k+1}\le(k+1)(a_k-1)+2.$$ Also, $$\lceil k!e\rceil=\frac{k!}{0!}+\frac{k!}{1!}+\frac{k!}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{k!}{k!}+1.$$

Comment: In fact, $R_k(3,3,\dots,3)=\lceil k!e\rceil$ for $k\le3,$ but $R_4(3,3,3,3)\lt66=\lceil4!e\rceil.$